# How to navigate to an Id on a page using UrlRouting

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I have a long page with several distinct sections. It's a terms page.

I want url's for the second section, "competition terms" to position next to the competition terms header.

Normally, I would have something like this: /mypage.aspx#competition-terms for the url but this doesn't seem to be working when I use url routing. I'm using web forms, not MVC.

At this point I'm unsure whether I've done something wrong, or its not possible.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your url after routing ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use routeName 'MyPage' for 'mypage.aspx' page then
`'/MyPage#competition-terms'` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The # is to "competition". When I add is to the terms page I see this in the address bar: http://localhost:3716/terms%23competition but it does not jump to the id="competition" on the terms page.